# How to draw a Panel only in the Shader editor node editor (object type based)?

Tags: python, panel

Like the question in the title, I would like to understand how to place a UI Panel only in the Editing of the Material nodes
So it would be "Shader Editor" in Object mode.
At this moment the panel is drawn in each node_tree.
This is causing me a problem.
THe code:

```
class ADDON_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_idname = "ADDON_PT_Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"
    bl_context = "scene"
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label("Hello World")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Poll the `ui_type`**

With the advent of more than one UI in a particular area type, when this is the case look at the `Area.ui_type`

Unaware of, but there may be a `bl_context` (or similar) class property to do this.  As with 99% of blender the UI code is there to peruse.

Look up the docs for options, put a print in draw method, or find quickly via blender's python console

```
>>> C.area.ui_type = 'XXXX'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "XXXX" 
not found in (, 'VIEW_3D', 'VIEW', 'UV', 
'CompositorNodeTree', 
'TextureNodeTree', 
'ShaderNodeTree', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET', 'TIMELINE', 'FCURVES', 'DRIVERS', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'CONSOLE', 'INFO', 'OUTLINER', 'PROPERTIES', 'FILE_BROWSER', 'PREFERENCES')
```

Notice there are three obvious candidates for nodetrees.

Test script.  Polls if the context area  `ui_type` is `'ShaderNodeTree'`

```
import bpy

class ADDON_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_idname = "ADDON_PT_Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"
    #bl_context = "scene"
    
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return context.area.ui_type == "ShaderNodeTree"    

    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        #print(context.space_data.ui_type)
        layout.label(text="Hello World")
        
bpy.utils.register_class(ADDON_PT_Panel)
```